# Issue with Overriding cart in Magento2.3.1

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, magento2.3.1, overriding

I want to add a custom button having a different value on the cart page I am facing issues with JS and won't understand what below line will do:

```
data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/action/update-shopping-cart":
          {"validationURL" : "/checkout/cart/updateItemQty"}
```

Do I need to override things for the files mentioned here?

How many files do I need to override?
1. I override the template file.
2. UpdatePost controller
3. JS file named: shopping-cart.js (error: https://prnt.sc/no1y6o )

Anything that I am doing wrong here, or some more files I need to override.

Comment: What exactly you want to do with custom button?

Comment: I am doing both quotable and Orderable products on same page but different action with some different button.

Comment: This is for updating the shopping cart 'update-shopping-cart' and you will have to send request to your custom controller through ajax or post to that controller, you need to change the post url before submitting the form through js, or simply redirect to custom controller and get the card items make it quotable. did you get it?

Comment: I have override the Updatepost controller

Comment: Ok then set the value="quotable" of your custom submit button then on controller check the post type if 'quotable', got it? this example will give you better idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Comment: What about the js file inside ja/action folder of checkout module